# No me selecciona los archivos seleccionados y tengo activado el OpenFileDialog.MultiSelect= true

Tags: c#, visual-studio

saludos cordiales para todos

El contexto es el siguiente : estoy en el desarrollo de un programa en C#  que permita convertir archivos `pdf` a `excel` , habilito la opción `OpenfileDialog.Multiselect` y eso me permite seleccionar 1 o mas archivos , hasta ahí bien =)

Además tengo un `listBox` donde aparecen los archivos seleccionados, un botón convertir y una carpeta de destino, es decir, el caso es simple : el usuario selecciona los archivos que quiera desde el pc , los sube al `listbox` , le especificas en que carpeta se van a almacenar los archivos convertidos y listo.

El problema es que solo me convierte el primero en la lista que yo seleccioné, 
 indagando me di cuenta que él tomaba el indice 0 dentro de la Matriz como primer registro y por eso de la lista solo me convierte el primer registro. La verdad solicito su ayuda para habilitar la opción de que, aun habilitando la propiedad `multiselect` del `OpenfileDIalog` , este me convierta todos los archivos que se seleccionaron.

Este es el proyecto:

```
Lista = ListBox
RutaOrigenArchivo = variable que especifica de donde provienen los archivos seleccionados para luego anidarlos con SautinSoft
```

Resumen : el logra convertirme el primer archivo que esta dentro de la lista de los que seleccione , quiero es que convierta todos los archivos que seleccione , no solo el primero

Quedo atento a su ayuda amigos

```
namespace convertidor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        /*FolderBrowserDialog significa que cuando el usuario de clic , nos mostrara un dialogo con la ruta
        entre carpetas*/
        FolderBrowserDialog CarpetaSalida;

        bool Convertir = false;
        string RutaArchivoOrigen;
        string NombreArchivoOrigen;
        string RutaArchivoDestino;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        /* Estas Variables nos permitan fijar una posición para el cursor para posteriormente  darle rangos a la figura
         y asi poder manipularla de izq-der / Arr-Ab , cuando le asignemos Left y Topy*/
        int posX = 0;
        int posY = 0;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label5.Text = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d");
        }

        private void BtnOrigenArchivoo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog CajaDialogo = new OpenFileDialog();
            CajaDialogo.FileName = "";
            CajaDialogo.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
            CajaDialogo.Filter = "Adobe PDF Files (.pdf)|*.pdf";
            CajaDialogo.Title = "Seleccione los archivos que desea Convertir";
            CajaDialogo.Multiselect = true;

            CajaDialogo.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            this.Activate();

            DialogResult Resultado = CajaDialogo.ShowDialog();

            if (Resultado == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string filename in CajaDialogo.FileNames)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(filename);
                    Lista.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(filename));  
                }     
            }

            //RutaArchivoOrigen = CajaDialogo.ToString();
            //aca  nos damos cuenta de que en la matriz , el tiene el indice sub-cero
            //que seria el primer archivo


            RutaArchivoOrigen = CajaDialogo.FileName;
            NombreArchivoOrigen = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RutaArchivoOrigen);
            RutaArchivoDestino = Path.GetDirectoryName(RutaArchivoOrigen);


            //textBox1.Text = CajaDialogo.FileName.ToString();


            textBox1.Text = CajaDialogo.FileName;

            Convertir = true;

        }


            private void BtnDestino_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Generamos un disparador que envia un mensaje en pantalla solicitandole al usuario información , 
            sobre donde alojar los nuevos documentos */
            MessageBox.Show("Indique a que carpeta desea Almacenar los archivos");

            CarpetaSalida = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (CarpetaSalida.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
             /*decimos que la caja de texto "TxtCarpetaDestinoo" alojara los datos de la Ruta y/o Directorio
              donde se alojára la información , y que la RutaDestino es igual a txtCarpetaSalida.*/
                TxtCarpetaDestinoo.Text = CarpetaSalida.SelectedPath;
                RutaArchivoDestino = TxtCarpetaDestinoo.Text;
                Convertir = true;
            }

        }


        private void BtnConvertir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string outFile = String.Empty;

            string pdfFile = RutaArchivoOrigen;
            MessageBox.Show("Un momento por favor se estan conviertiendo los archivos",
                "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (Convertir)

            {
               t
                SautinSoft.PdfFocus ArchivoPDF = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

                ArchivoPDF.OpenPdf(@RutaArchivoOrigen);
                ArchivoPDF.ToExcel(@RutaArchivoDestino + "\\" + NombreArchivoOrigen + ".xls");

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@RutaArchivoDestino);

                outFile = Path.ChangeExtension(pdfFile, ".xls");
                // este metodo nos permite abrir el documento recien convertido automaticamente 
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(outFile) { UseShellExecute = true });

                MessageBox.Show("Proceso Exitos , Archivos Convertidos...");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor Selecciona un Archivo Valido");

            }


        }

        private void Panel3_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            { // Igualamos las propiedades del panel , contra las variables creadas PosX = 0 ; PosY=0;  antes definidas
                posX = e.X;
                posY = e.Y;
            }

            else
            {
                Left = Left + (e.X - posX);
                Top = Top + (e.Y - posY);
            }
        }


        private void BtnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Lista.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                Lista.Items.Clear();
                MessageBox.Show("Completado");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No hay archivos");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A ver. Tu metes todos los archivos seleccionados en `Lista`. Pero luego...nunca usas ese listbox. En tu `BtnConvertir_Click`, deberás hacer un foreach de todos los archivos que estan en esa lista, no de `RutaArchivoOrigen` que es solo uno de los archivos.

Comment: Muchas gracias AMigo , tu podiras por favor a darle solucion a este caso depronto diciendome como deberia quedar ,me siento algo perdido en esta parte , Gracias

Comment: Es muy sencillo si lo piensas. En `BtnConvertir_Click` debes ejecutar el código que esta dentro de `if (Convertir)` una vez por cada archivo que tengas en lista.Lo que debes hacer es algo como `foreach (var archivo in Lista.items) { RutaArchivoOrigen=archivo; SautinSoft.PdfFocus ArchivoPDF = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

                ArchivoPDF.OpenPdf(@RutaArchivoOrigen);...`. Prefiero no darte una solución completa, ya que si lo piensas probablemente acabes aprendiendo mejor :)

Comment: Pikon , Hombre muchas muchas gracias por asesorarme , y respecto a lo ultimo  "Prefiero no darte una solución completa, ya que si lo piensas probablemente acabes aprendiendo mejor  "  estoy de acuerdo , palabras sabias

Comment: Amigo como estas , no he podido dar con la solución, no se que pasa pero el algoritmo que creo no compila ...ayuda !